# why doesn't bash IFS value split expansion argument?

Tags: bash

```
>export FOOBAR=foobar; IFS=b echo ${FOOBAR}
```

I was expecting to see

```
foo ar
```

but I see

```
foobar
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IFS hasnt yet taken effect. add another ";":

```
FOOBAR=foobar IFS=b; echo ${FOOBAR}
```

In `man bash` section *SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION*
you can read (abbreviated):

> ```
>   When a simple command is executed
> ```
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) are saved for later processing.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded.
> 3. ...
> 4. The text after the = in each variable assignment ... [are] assigned to the variable.

so the IFS=b is done after expanding $FOOBAR.

Comment: Excellent. As-amended, no need for me to maintain my own answer here.

Comment: This can't be the answer.  From a little further along in that same part of the man page: _"Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment."_ Which means that the command being executed should see the `IFS` variable as was assigned, and wouldn't be seen after the command has been invoked.  Otherwise, what would be the point of having this feature?

Answer (score -1):

[edit]I removed the technically incorrect answer.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html
"This variable determines how Bash recognizes fields, or word boundaries, when it interprets character strings."

Comment: *All* unquoted expansions are string-split (unless in `[[ ]]` or other special syntax suppressing that behavior); no loops needed.

Comment: I didn't say a loop was needed, I said, ie, which means, for example, a loop. However, with that said, I see the error in my reply.

Comment: Certainly, but you imply very strongly that `echo $FOOBAR` does not, in and of itself, string-split the value in FOOBAR before passing those values to `echo`. This implication is incorrect.

Comment: ...by contrast, @meuh's answer -- preceding yours by two minutes -- is spot-on for accuracy; the only reason I added my own was that it's potentially lacking on completeness.